# Loading html document with head and scripts into element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm using custom web components with shadow dom to load an html file into the element, I can't seem to find a way to load it as an html file without having a delay the header scripts and style links.

In other words, scripts are not loading and external css files in the head tag are delayed till after the html is fully loaded.

the html file looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>My Document</title>
    <link href="/MyStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/MyScripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Other Main Tags -->

    <script src="/AnotherScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
customElements.define('ui-include', class extends HTMLElement {

    async connectedCallback() {
        let ref = this.getAttribute('ref')

        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        shadow.innerHTML = 'Loading...';

        fetch(`/documentviewer.aspx/GetContent`,
            {
                body: JSON.stringify({ reference: ref }),
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                // r.d is the response html string (html file example above)
                shadow.innerHTML = r.d ;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.error(e)
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('done')
            })
    }
})
```

HTML:

```html
<ui-include ref="Document_123"></ui-include>
```

After the page is loaded, when inspecting the `ui-include`. header tag is not showing anymore. like it was unwraped, heres a screenshot:

[image]

*Please Note that the selected script in the image is `/MyScripts.js` not `/MyScripts`*

How can I treat the html response string as an actual document and load it into the web component?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using an obsolete Doctype that triggers [Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode). Causing browsers to simulate bugs found in Netscape 4 and IE 5 is usually undesirable!

Comment: What is inside 'r.d'? Can you share it, may be then I can help you with it.

Comment: @DeepakDixit i edited my question. its the `html` response file example

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of DOM Parser like this:

```
customElements.define('ui-include', class extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
        let ref = this.getAttribute('ref')
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        shadow.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
        fetch(`/documentviewer.aspx/GetContent`, {
                body: JSON.stringify({ reference: ref }),
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                shadow.children[0].remove();
                const dp = new DOMParser();
                const f = document.createDocumentFragment();
                const pDom = dp.parseFromString(r.d, 'text/html');
                f.appendChild(pDom.documentElement)
                shadow.appendChild(f);
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e))
            .then(() => console.log('done'));
    }
})
```

Comment: I first got 'shadow.children[0]' is undefined. then removed that line since there is not children just 'loading..' text. then the parser stated: `DOMException: Node.appendChild: May not add a Document as a child`

Comment: Can you check my updated answer and if its not working , create a fiddle link and share it.

Comment: Thanks but still same error. its on  `appendChild` heres a fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/fwrknL50/6/

Comment: I updated my answer with the use of ** documentElement** which should work now. Try now.

Comment: Working well! but still not treating it as an html document, scripts are not loaded and styles are delayed to after the html is appended to the shadow dom

Answer (score 0):

> How can I treat the html response string as an actual document and load it into the web component?

If you want to transform a string into a document you should use [createHTMDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument).
But the content a Web Component is not a document but only a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

For this reason you cannot have  or  elements in a Custom Element or in a Shadow DOM.

The way you loaded the string with `innerHTML` is valid as much as using `appendChild()` with an Element or a DocumentFragment.